# How can I make my IsItAHoliday function more efficient?

Tags: c#, function, datetime, performance

I have a method that is supposed to return 1 if it is a weekend or one of these holidays: New Years Day, Memorial Day, Independence Day, Labor Day, Thanksgiving Day & Christmas Day, and 0 otherwise. I have chosen to implement the code using a combination of DateTime.DayOfYear and DateTime.IsLeapYear, but I feel like this is really inefficient, and also, makes it more difficult to do holidays like Memorial Day (final Monday of May!). How can I achieve my goal efficiently, and without hardcoding the holidays that change dates every year?

Here is my current implementation:

```
    private int IsItAHoliday(DateTime time)
    {
        // Assume it is not a weekend
        int isWeekendOrHoliday = 0;

        // TODO: Memorial Day, Labor Day, Thanksgiving
        // Declare holidays
        int christmasDayNonLeapYearIndex = 359;
        int christmasDayLeapYearIndex = 360;
        int newYearsDayIndex = 1;
        int independenceDayNonLeapYearIndex = 185;
        int independenceDayLeapYearIndex = 186;

        // Find out if time falls on a weekend
        if (time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            isWeekendOrHoliday = 1;
        }
        // Find out if time falls on a holiday
        // Leap year
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(time.Year))
        {
            if ((time.DayOfYear == christmasDayLeapYearIndex) || (time.DayOfYear == independenceDayLeapYearIndex) || (time.DayOfYear == newYearsDayIndex))
            {
                isWeekendOrHoliday = 1;
            }
        }
        // Non-leap year
        else if (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(time.Year))
        {
            if ((time.DayOfYear == christmasDayNonLeapYearIndex) || (time.DayOfYear == independenceDayNonLeapYearIndex) || (time.DayOfYear == newYearsDayIndex))
            {
                isWeekendOrHoliday = 1;
            }
        }

        return isWeekendOrHoliday;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common approach is to define set of rules that describes a holiday date:

```
public interface IHoliday
{
  bool isHoliday(DateTime date);
}
```

Then implement the interfaces for different holiday schemas. For example, exact date holiday:

```
public class ExactDayHoliday : IHoliday
{
  public int Day {get; set;}
  public int Month {get; set;}

  public bool isHoliday(DateTime date)
  {
    return date.Month == month && date.Day == day;
  }
}
```

Another example of rule: a day of n-th weeks of the month.

```
public class DayOfWeekHoliday : IHoliday
{
    public int Nth { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }

    public bool isHoliday(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.Month == Month && date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek && (date.Day - 1) / 7 == (Nth - 1);
    }
}
```

Create list of rules for all holidays. For example:

```
List<IHoliday> holidays = new List<IHoliday> {new ExactDayHoliday {Month = 12, Day = 25}, new DayOfWeekHoliday {Nth = 1, DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday, Month = 9}};
```

And the last step (check for given date):

```
bool isHoliday = holidays.Any(rule => rule.IsHoliday(date));
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. How can I extend this solution to holidays that don't fall on the same day each year?

Comment: My solution was not extensible for dynamic holidays. Dmitriy's answer is good and extensible. You should have a look at the following link for dynamic holidays because rule definitions are not easy. `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11666/Dynamic-Holiday-Date-Calculator` Thanks.

Comment: Add another IHoliday rule. Hope you understand an idea

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you use Enumerations if you will be hard coding every event you need your application to support for example :

```
    public enum Holidays{
    newYearsDayIndex = 1,
    independenceDayNonLeapYearIndex = 185,
        independenceDayLeapYearIndex = 186,
    christmasDayNonLeapYearIndex = 359,
        christmasDayLeapYearIndex = 360
    }
```

Then use the value of each as the day index of a holiday and the name to explain why this day is a holiday

```
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Holidays)); --> For values which you will use as days Index
    Enum.GetNames(typeof(Holidays)); --> For Names which you will use to describe the picked date
```

You may also consider separating Leap holidays and non leap holidays each in separate Enumeration with your naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to check for `YEAR` in holidays , because they appear on the same dates every year, like say Dec 25, 1 Jan etc.

I quickly compiled some code:

```
public class Holiday
{
    public int Day {get; private set;}
    public int Month {get; private set;}
    public Holiday(int day, int month)
    {
        this.Day = day;
        this.Month = month;
    }

    public bool IsEqual(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return ((this.Day == dateTime.Day) && (this.Month == dateTime.Month));
    }
}

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    private static List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>();

    public static void RegisterHoliday(Holiday holiday)
    {
        holidays.Add(holiday);
    }

    public static bool IsHoliday(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        foreach (Holiday holiday in holidays)
        {
            if (holiday.IsEqual(dateTime)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool IsWeekend(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (dateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) || (dateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday);
    }
}
```

Now Add Holidays using the `Register` method and use the extensions.
   `DateTimeExtensions.RegisterHoliday(new Holiday(25, 12));`

`DateTime dateTimeToCheck = new DateTime(2013, 12, 25);`
   `return dateTimeToCheck.IsHoliday() || dateTimeToCheck.IsWeekend();`